# Set a title and description for each photo in carouse android

Tags: java, android

I am using a carouselView library for my app. https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview

The images are displaying and the carousel is working but how do I set a title and description below each image as it slides for each image.

I have a string containing all the title and text for each image.

e.g

```
<string name="first_image_title">First image title</string>
<string name="first_image_desc">This is a description for first image title</string>

<string name="second_image_title">2nd image title</string>
<string name="second_image_desc">This is a description for the second image title</string>

<string name="third_image_title">3rd image title</string>
<string name="third_image_desc">This is a description for the third image title</string>
```

All these are supposed to be placed below the sliding images (for each image.)

**fragment_safety.xml**

Containing the image and where the title and description for each image supposed to be

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="fragments.SafetyFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabContent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner2">

    <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
        android:id="@+id/carouselView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:pageColor="#00000000"
        app:radius="6dp"
        app:slideInterval="5000"
        app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/carouselView"/>

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textDesc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTitle"/>

</RelativLayout>
```

**SafetyFragment.java**

According to the doc, I am supposed to implement ViewListener for customView but I cant wrap my head around how to do this....Get all the titles and description in the string and set them for each of the images sliding.

```
public class SafetyFragment extends Fragment {

private CarouselView carouselView;
private int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.image1, 
R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, 
R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, 
R.drawable.image6};

public SafetyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety, container, false);
   carouselView = root.findViewById(R.id.carouselView);


    ImageListener imagesListenerx = new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
            Glide.with(SafetyFragment.this).load(sampleImages[position]).into(imageView);
        }
    };

    ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
            View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety, null);
            //set view attributes here

            return customView;
        }
    };

    carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
    carouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);

   return root;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this.

1.**Declare a string array for each text you want to display in each carousel**

```
private String[] titles = {"One", "Two", "Three"}
```

**2. Set a custom view listener and get the view in the layout**

```
ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
    int i;
    @Override
    public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety, null);
        //set view attributes here

        safety_title = customView.findViewById(R.id.safetyTextTitle);

        safety_images = customView.findViewById(R.id.safetyImages);          
        
        Glide.with(SafetyFragment.this).load(sampleImages[position]).into(safety_images);

        //Very Important
        safety_title.setText(titles[position]);
        return customView;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you  can create a custom view and bind views with the data

```
 ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {

    @Override
    public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
        View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_custom, null);
        //set view attributes here

        return customView;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way:

```
ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
            View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_carousel, null);
            //set view attributes here
            TextView car_title = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
            ImageView car_image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);          

            car_title.setText(sampleTitle[position]);
            car_image.setImageResource(sampleImages[position]);
            return customView;
        }
    };
```

While custom view in **custom_carousel.xml** will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/textDesc"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="test" />   
    
</RelativeLayout>
```